# How to return a value from a closure back to a function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, closures

My problem is that the value from the Request function is only returned after the second pass through it.
I tried both @escaping and Dispatch, but the value still only comes back after the second pass.
The main point of these functions is that you need to take the two fields "Login" and "Password" and send them to the server, and then get a response in JSON format and unpack it, and then log in or not in the application
Here's the code:

```
// request function
func request(url: String, login: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (String)->()){
        
        guard let connectionUrl = URL(string: url) else { return }
        let parameters = ["username": login, "password": password]
        var request = URLRequest(url: connectionUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else
        { return }
        
        request.httpBody = httpBody
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, _) in
            if let response = response  { print(response) }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let result =  self.parse(json: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                completion(result)
            }
           
        }.resume()
      //  return result
    }

// Button handler 
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let login = loginTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else {return}
        server.request(url: urlString, login: login, password: password) {
             result in
//It goes here even on the first pass and assigns everything correctly.
                if result == "s kaifom" {
                    self.server.answerFromServer = true
                } else {
                    self.server.answerFromServer = false
                }
//After passing the last curly bracket the value is reset and then falls into the "else" block
        }

//  This "if" is skipped on the first pass and falls right into the "else" block

        if self.server.answerFromServer && !login.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty{
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GuestScreen") as! GuestViewController;
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
        }
        else{
            sender.shake()
        }
    }
```

Comment: "//After passing the last curly bracket the value is reset and then falls into the "else" block" No, that's not it. It's not "reseted". Add a print before that curly brace, like `print("Inside closure")` and just after: `print("outside closure")` which one is printed first? Which one did you expect to see first in console? You don't want to return, you want to do the if/else ONCE you get `result` call back.

Comment: since your comments says "everything is assigned correctly", that means you got response from the server right? so what is the  result == "s kaifom" true or false?

Comment: "s kaifom" means true

Comment: The first one was "outside closure" and the second one was "Inside closure".

Comment: And when you press the button again (for the second pass of the function), the print is also displayed first outside the clogger, and then inside it. However, in this case the function works correctly. @Larme

Comment: You are missing the asynchrone concept. The order of the print is normal if you know that's asynchrone. Create a method `showGuestOrShake()`, where you'd put that other code, and call it inside the closure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple, you just have to push all the code into the closure.

```
server.request(url: urlString, login: login, password: password) {
             result in
                if result == "s kaifom" {
                    self.server.answerFromServer = true
                } else {
                    self.server.answerFromServer = false
                }
            print("inside closure")
            if self.server.answerFromServer && !login.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty{
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GuestScreen") as! GuestViewController;
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
            }
            else{
                sender.shake()
            }
        }
```